# What do the symbols on the map mean while fishing?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I've noticed that while fishing, the fish are marked by icons on the minimap. I seem to remember learning that blue markers indicated trophy (read: inedible) fish, while the yellow markers indicated edible fish.

[image]

What do the large circles with rings around them indicate? From experience, these haven't turned out to be particularly large or rare fish.

Comment: Anecdotally, the circle seems to indicate 'rarity'. It's hard to be 100% sure because you aren't directly told which symbol you're interacting with and as the screenshot shows there are often several of them clustered together

Comment: I agree with this too, I've found them to be the largest or rarest type of fish at the spot. If your line breaks, you lose the opportunity to snag the fish and have to come back later. As evidenced in the camp tour 'Liege of the Lake' with Gladiolus.

Comment: @DavidYell I'm not sure about that. Whenever I catch them, they tend to be somewhat small. I've also caught big ones, so it's not consistently large or small. However, when I was catching a fish for a quest, I used the right lure, caught that fish, and noticed the pulsing circle was gone from the minimap immediately afterwards.

Comment: Guess we'd need to test in a spot where the fish are known.

Comment: @DavidYell that would be cool if you want to do that! I may get around to it after I get some of the other side stuff out of the way. I finally got a rod upgrade to keep my line from breaking in .2 seconds so that's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *in-game icon reference*, the large dots with circles around them represent **uncommon** fish (red box in image).

This icon key can be accessed from the party menu and pressing the key indicated in the bottom right corner (green box in image) to find the significance of other icons, as well.

[image: Key for FF XV icons]

Comment: WHAAAAT? How did people even THINK that it was anything else?

Comment: @Vemonus I don't think the game ever outright tells you what those symbols means; I only found these by accident when I went to look up what the symbol that shows up after a Phoenix Down actually does lol

Answer (score 5):

According to [this guide on fishing in FFXV](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5ficp3/fishing_tips_from_an_addicted_angler_wip/), it looks like the bordered circles indicate that the lure you are currently using attracts that fish.

> Some fishing holes will have signs posted by them to tell you what kinds of fish there are, but most do not and the signs are incomplete anyways. **Circles on the minimap will pulse with a white border if you have the correct bait type to attract that fish** (I don’t know if this is skill level related or if it is an automatic feature straight from level 1).

However, this is incorrect, as seen in the in-game reference provided in @Leon7C's answer.

Comment: I vaguely remember the first time you can fish the tutorial explains what the dots mean, but i cant remember. The Strategy guide i have, says that some stronger, end game fish will appear as large gold dots if your fishing is high enough to track them. Outside of that, i have no definitive information

Comment: @Mayshar prior to reading this, I had thought the bordered dots indicated fish you hadn't caught before, but now that I've read this, I think it's correct. Haven't done a *ton* of fishing since that, so it may be wrong, but it seems likely.

Comment: If i actually read the fishing section in my strategy guide, i bet it explains it all, but i havent done so. I only wanted to hit level 10 to get the trophy and have paid no mind to fishing outside of that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5h8kff/complete_list_of_fish_locations_and_effective) the big or small dots just identify different types of fish. Note: the top comment in the thread has a formatted table for easy reference.

Eg. "Allural Sea Bass" will always be a Large Yellow dot. In general, fish indicated by the large icon (dot with a circle around it) are more challenging than the other fish. Fish indicated by just a dot are typically easier to catch.

The linked guide gives specific lures to use on each fish, but some fish will be attracted by multiple types or simply by *any* lure. It's a good guide and I've used it quite a bit, because the official guide is *severely* lacking in fishing details.

Since you mentioned you're just trying to get to level 10 fishing, it would be advantageous to target the large dots - both blue and yellow. They offer more SP (Skill experience points) than the smaller fish, and you'll likely catch a few small fish before the big one takes the bait anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I've noticed the dots change when I equip various lures...

Comment: @Vemonus That could be, but I haven't noticed that. Fish sometimes 'update' seemingly randomly, and some fish will despawn when the time changes from day->evening or evening->nighttime, etc. I've fished quite a bit, and before finding that guide I was in the habit of trying every single lure just to get a single fish to bite. The dot never changed in those cases, and the fish would only respond to one or two lures, even after casting each lure multiple times (sometimes it doesn't 'take' on the first throw, and doing something akin to fly fishing can help)